# How to run PowerShell in CMD

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script inside cmd command line. Someone gave me an example and it worked:

```
powershell.exe -noexit "& 'c:\Data\ScheduledScripts\ShutdownVM.ps1'"
```

But the problem is my PowerShell script has input parameters, so I tried, but it doesn't work:

```
powershell.exe -noexit "& 'D:\Work\SQLExecutor.ps1 -gettedServerName "MY-PC" ' "
```

The error is:

> The term 'D:\Work\SQLExecutor.ps1 -gettedServerName "MY-PC" ' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use -noexit ? This means when your script completes the shell will hang around, possibly blocking the execution of the batch file in CMD.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You need to separate the arguments from the file path:

```
powershell.exe -noexit "& 'D:\Work\SQLExecutor.ps1 ' -gettedServerName 'MY-PC'"
```

Another option that may ease the syntax using the File parameter and positional parameters:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -file "D:\Work\SQLExecutor.ps1" "MY-PC"
```

Comment: So basically you just need to add `-file`.

Answer (score 15):

I'd like to add the following to Shay Levy's correct answer:
You can make your life easier if you create a little batch script `run.cmd` to launch your powershell script:

**run.cmd**

```
@echo off & setlocal
set batchPath=%~dp0
powershell.exe -noexit -file "%batchPath%SQLExecutor.ps1" "MY-PC"
```

Put it in the same path as `SQLExecutor.ps1` and from now on you can run it by simply double-clicking on  `run.cmd`.

---

**Note:**

- If you require command line arguments inside the run.cmd batch, simply pass them as `%1` ... `%9` (or use `%*` to pass all parameters) to the powershell script, i.e.
  `powershell.exe -noexit -file "%batchPath%SQLExecutor.ps1" %*`
- The variable `batchPath` contains the executing path of the batch file itself (this is what the expression `%~dp0` is used for). So you just put the powershell script in the same path as the calling batch file.

Comment: You can do the same with `@powershell.exe -noexit -file "%~dp0SQLExecutor.ps1" "MY-PC"`.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the varialble `batchPath`, yes of course you can do so. But due to `setlocal` the variable does not harm, since the variable's lifetime ends when the script exits. @NunoAndré

Answer (score 7):

Try just:

```
powershell.exe -noexit D:\Work\SQLExecutor.ps1 -gettedServerName "MY-PC"
```