# Run powershell scripts in emacs

Tags: windows, powershell, vim, emacs, cmd

I installed powershell package in emacs. I launched the powershell using M-x powershell. In the powershell window, I am able to run command like ls etc, but I am not able to execute powershell scripts. I tried to use cmd as a default shell in emacs and execute the powershell script from it as described here;

[How to run PowerShell in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436405/how-to-run-powershell-in-cmd)

but it freezes. Similarly, when I am try to run vim in powershell/cmd within emacs it freezes. I want to point out that scripts and vim is working fine in powershell and cmd, if I am running it outside emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `M-x powershell` and `M-x shell`, the terminal is "dumb" and only understands programs that *print*, but not programs that go *fullscreen*.

So, it will work with `ls`, `cat`, and `cd`, but will fail on `vim`, `man`, and `less`. I bet your script tries to open `vim`, no?

This restriction exists for a reason: when a program goes fullscreen, it captures all keyboard input. So if you open `vim` and type `C-x`, does it run the Emacs command for `C-x` or the Vim command? If you always run the Emacs command, that means when you type `j`, it will insert `j` into the Emacs buffer instead of scrolling down in Vim. Vim will become unusable. If you always run the Vim command, that means you can no longer use `C-x C-c` to get out of Emacs, since the command will be absorbed by Vim.

One workaround is to use `M-x term`. In `term` all keystrokes are sent to the program, so you can open and use Vim like normal. To run an Emacs command, start with `C-c`. You can read more about it [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Term-Mode.html#Term-Mode). I'm not sure it it exists in Windows.

Another workaround to use `emacsclient`:

```
;; in init.el
(server-start)

# in a shell
$ emacsclient file.txt
```

This will open the file in your existing Emacs window. When you're done editting the file, press `C-x #` to go back to the shell.

Comment: No the script is not trying to open vim. Is is just compiling stuffs, set up some environment variable. I think something wrong with the powershell.el thing.

Comment: What error message do you get when the script fails?

Comment: It is working now. I was using auto-complete, which was not adding .\ at the beginning of the path. After I added .\ it is working. However, when I am running a script using, powershell -noexit "& ""D:\build.ps1""", it is getting stuck like vim. So it may be the same reason like vim.