# SQLCMD , 'tee' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: sql, powershell, batch-file, sqlcmd

I've fetchDb.bat file that calls many .sql files to 
upgrade the database to last version

this is the command used to execute .Sql File content

```
sqlcmd %Sqlinstance% -d DataBase -i "fileName.sql" | tee "FileNameOutput.txt"
```

but this message Always appear for me 
'tee' is not recognized as an internal or external command , operable program or batch file.

Comment: `Tee` is an alias for `Tee-Object`, which belongs to PowerShell only. Is that part of the code being executed in a PowerShell shell or session or is that in a cmd shell? If this is a direct line of code from a batch file, then that is why it does not work. You can run this snippet from PowerShell if you pass in `%Sqlinstance%` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`tee ( Tee-Object )`** is cmdlet which is supported in **powershell**. so you have to use powershell for this **or** you can use below command to **save output to file** in bat

```
 COMMAND >> Filename
```

in your case :

```
sqlcmd %Sqlinstance% -d DataBase -i "fileName.sql" >> "FileNameOutput.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks but is there is any other solution to pass this command from powershell to Cmd ?

Comment: yes. follow this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436405/how-to-run-powershell-in-cmd

Answer (score 0):

From a CMD shell, you can do either of the following, but make sure your batch file only echoes what you want to see in your output file. This will allow you to use `tee`.

**Using a batch file:**

```
PowerShell.exe -Command ".\fetchDB.bat | tee 'filenameoutput.txt'"
```

**Using commands that can be passed to PowerShell:**

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "$sqlinstance='servername'; sqlcmd.exe -S $sqlinstance -d Test -i 'fileName.sql' | tee 'filenameoutput.txt'"

# You can use this option if your CMD shell has variable sqlinstance defined
powershell.exe -Command "sqlcmd.exe -S %sqlinstance% -d Test -i 'fileName.sql' | tee 'filenameoutput.txt'"
```

From a PowerShell console, you can just call the fully qualified batch file and pipe to `tee`.

```
.\fetchdb.bat | tee "filenameoutput.txt"
```

Comment: thanks I also tried unix utility , and it's works fine